# How to transpose only one row of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iel4A.png)

I want the accuracy row to be in the column part

Comment: Maybe: `. <- df[nrow(df),]; df <- df[-nrow(df),]; df[unlist(.[1])] <- unlist(.[-1])`

Answer (score -1):

Here a step by step manual solution with base R

### Code

```
#Data
df <-
  data.frame(X = c(1:3,"accurracy"), precision = runif(4), recall = runif(4), f1.score = runif(4))

#Save the last row data in a vector
accurracy <- unlist(df[nrow(df),])

#Eliminate the last row from the original data.frame
df <- df[-nrow(df),]

#Create a new column
df$"accurracy" <- accurracy[-1]

df
```

### Output

```
  X precision    recall  f1.score          accurracy
1 1 0.6075635 0.4839641 0.3071190   0.12418847065419
2 2 0.5337823 0.3673568 0.8207251  0.951568570220843
3 3 0.2854789 0.7080209 0.8552161 0.0459401197731495
```